# Objective - C: Hidding a button through a delegate

Tags: ios, uibutton, int, hidden

I have two views a levelComplete view and a levelSelector view. What I would like to do is when the levelComplete shows or the `ViewDidLoad` occurs on that view I would like to send a delegate to the level selector to show a button in the view and then make that button  `UserInteractionEnabled` so then I will then be able to programme that button to do something if its not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to necessarily do it via a delegate. Coz you can do it in a simpler way as well. When you call your secondView, just tell your button to hide. So your modified code to calling the second view controller becomes:

```
-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender {
  secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  
  self.secondviewData = second; 
  sender.hidden=YES;
  secondviewData.passedValue = textfield.text;
  [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

And then you can set it to visible when your view loads up again using viewDidLoad. I can tell you how to do it via delegates if you need. Lemme know what works best.

**EDIT - Solution by Delegates**

Your secondView's Header file will be as follows:

```
@protocol SecondViewHandlerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)viewHasBeenLoaded:(BOOL)success;

@end

@interface secondview :UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UILabel *label;  
  NSString *passedValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *passedValue;

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation file of secondView(.m), synthesise the delegate first by `@synthesize delegate;` . After this, in your `viewDidLoad` of secondView, add the following line:

```
[[self delegate] viewHasBeenLoaded:YES];
```

That should be enough for your secondView. Now onto the firstViewController, perform the following steps:

In the header file (.h), import your second view and implement the protocol:

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController <SecondViewHandlerDelegate>{
..
..
}
```

In the implementation file (.m) of your firstViewController, implement this method:

```
- (void)viewHasBeenLoaded:(BOOL)success
{
    NSLog("Delegate Method Called");
    [myButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

And finally, in your code when you call the secondView, add this line:
    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
    second.delegate = self;
    ...

That should solve your purpose. I'd appreciate if you could mark the answer as correct as well. Thanks :)

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me by delegates instead but I am still greatful for your answer

Comment: sorry but i am slightly confused about your edit as you have used the second view multiple times and you have used the first once, I am probably being stupid.

Comment: Your second view has a delegate, which the first one implements. So when your second view is loaded, it sends a message to all the classes that have interest, i.e, that have implemented second view's protocol. So the first view receives a message from second view saying, "Okay Boss. I have finished loading. Do what you want to". Then first view hides the button. 
PS: Though I still prefer the approach without delegates for your problem, its up to you to decide.

Comment: Right i am going to reword my question so you will hopefully make me able to understand further

Comment: The above solution that I've written using delegates will work for your described problem. Define and create a protocol in levelComplete view and have the levelSelector implement that protocol, i.e., levelSelector will set itself as the delegate by: [levelComplete setDelegate: self]; Then when your view loads in levelComplete, send a message to your delegate saying it has loaded using the way mentioned above. Then when you receive that message in levelSelector, do what you need to with the button: [button setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];, etc. Hope this helps

Comment: Hey I have just tried out your code and it did not work any other suggestions or code

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you implement the protocol as specified in the example? Can you describe what're you seeing?

Comment: Don't worry I have fixed it but is there another way to do this line of code because my view does not need to  present my other view with the delegate The Line of code: secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; second.delegate = self;     [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Right to re-word my previous comment I want to set delegat to self even though I'm not transferring views